# gazebo_ros_pkgs - Erro

Tags: ros

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

When I do the downloading

`cd ~ / catkin_ws / src`

`git clone https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs.git`

the following error occurs when used the `catkin_make`.

```
Linking CXX shared library /home/orbit/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_ros_depth_camera.so
[ 95%] Built target gazebo_ros_depth_camera
Scanning dependencies of target gazebo_ros_paths_plugin
[ 96%] Building CXX object gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_ros_paths_plugin.cpp.o
/home/orbit/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp: In destructor ‘virtual gazebo::GazeboRosApiPlugin::~GazeboRosApiPlugin()’:
/home/orbit/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp:43:3: error: ‘DisconnectSigInt’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
/home/orbit/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void gazebo::GazeboRosApiPlugin::Load(int, char**)’:
/home/orbit/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp:111:19: error: ‘ConnectSigInt’ is not a member of ‘gazebo::event::Events’
Linking CXX shared library /home/orbit/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libgazebo_ros_paths_plugin.so
[ 96%] Built target gazebo_ros_paths_plugin
[ 96%] Built target dummy_app
Scanning dependencies of target effort_controllers
[ 96%] Building CXX object ros_controllers/effort_controllers/CMakeFiles/effort_controllers.dir/src/joint_effort_controller.cpp.o
make[2]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.dir/src/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/CMakeFiles/gazebo_ros_api_plugin.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 97%] Building CXX object ros_controllers/effort_controllers/CMakeFiles/effort_controllers.dir/src/joint_velocity_controller.cpp.o
[ 97%] Building CXX object ros_controllers/effort_controllers/CMakeFiles/effort_controllers.dir/src/joint_position_controller.cpp.o
Linking CXX shared library /home/orbit/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libeffort_controllers.so
[ 97%] Built target effort_controllers
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Best regards,

Eduardo

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3403/gazebo_ros_pkgs---erro./) by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-07-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-01**:
The link is protected.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-01**:
Sorry, the new link is: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1W9MqE709L631-lsado2MU9NQA7Iz6Q-KdJVlgrVaDYw/edit?usp=sharing

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-02**:
p.s. try https://gist.github.com for posting code snippets, its better than google docs :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

A lot has changed the past week in how Gazebo and gazebo_ros_pkgs is installed (SDF has been split into a stand-alone debian).

I encourage you to re-read and redo the instructions on the [installation](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages), close this ticket and create a new one if you continue to have issues.

---

Originally posted by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) with karma: 369 on 2013-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I believe you need to build Gazebo from source using the default branch.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-01**:
This is correct, there is a new event we added in Gazebo 1.9 (the default branch)

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-02**:
Hi, when I compile source Gazebo (http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install#Compile_Instructions) I have following error: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XN2T9cy_4o1x6Cy0dsXRuTbrFgsONKtHu3WUzkaJ1Vs/edit

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-02**:
Are you sure got all of these?

```
sudo apt-get install libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler libboost-all-dev freeglut3-dev cmake libogre-dev libtar-dev
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libcegui-mk2-dev

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-02**:\
Gazebo installed using the source code, I used the following link: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/get/default.zip and worked. But the package gazebo_ros_pkgs is not worked. Erro: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5912369

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-02**:\
I think the above issue ``gazebo/sensors/DepthCameraSensor.hh: No such file or directory`` is still a Gazebo install issue - try downloading using ``hg clone``, not a zip file? I'm not sure.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-02**:\
Hello, coleman and nkoenig, Your tip worked, I  managed compile the 'Gazebo' and 'gazebo_ros_pkg'. 
Many thanks!

**Comment by [FiliusFortunae](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/412/filiusfortunae/) on 2013-07-06**:\
I am having a similar error with DepthCameraSensor.hh ( https://gist.github.com/ftalex/5938868 ) when I run catkin make for the gazebo_ros_packages. I had installed Gazebo from the mercurial repository and that runs. Thanks for any assistance.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-06**:\
Hi FiliusFortunae, you must remove your installation (Gazebo and ROS) and reinstall the (Gazebo from source and ros-groovy-ros-base) and recreate the ambience of ROS (~ / catkin_ws). You must follow the instructions of the links: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages. 
Don't forget to install the dependencies, which are described in the link "Compile Instructions".

**Comment by [FiliusFortunae](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/412/filiusfortunae/) on 2013-07-07**:\
I tried this, however when I tried only base it gave me this error ( https://gist.github.com/ftalex/5942485 ) so I installed ros-groovy-desktop (which doesn't include gazebo so I thought would work) however I got the same .hh errors again, I also posted a question: http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3479/gazebo-ros-packages-fatal-error/

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-07**:\
You must install the dependencies to build the package, for example, ros-groovy-trajectory-msgs, ros-groovy-angles, ros-tf-groovy, groovy-geometry-msgs ros-groovy-and-actionlib-msgs. After installing these dependencies try again.

**Comment by [FiliusFortunae](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/412/filiusfortunae/) on 2013-07-07**:\
I had all those, I believe they come with ros-groovy-desktop. Thanks for replying

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-08**:\
The latest changes to Gazebo 1.9 in the default branch are causing gazebo\_ros\_pkgs to not build. Will be investigating today.

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-10**:\
Hi davtcoleman, I was following the installation tutorial here(http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages) and I'm getting the exact same error as posted in the question. Gazebo 1.8.6 was installed from pre-compiled binaries for Ubuntu 12.04 and that is working well. Do I install Gazebo from source and then try?

**Comment by [FiliusFortunae](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/412/filiusfortunae/) on 2013-07-10**:\
I created another question on the same topic and someone suggested a workaround - I have just switched to working with the gazebo in groovy but check out http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3479/gazebo-ros-packages-fatal-error/?comment=3494#comment-3494

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-10**:\
Hi Shehzi, I just updated the gazebo\_ros\_pkgs installation page an hour ago, we are making final changes for the release of ROS Hydro and Gazebo 1.9. I'd say try again tomorrow after we get everything worked out - we're a little bit in a limbo state right now waiting on the build farm.

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-10**:\
That is really good! Thank you davetcoleman, I will try installing the packages tomorrow and let you know how it goes.

**Comment by [EduardoMaciel](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/270/eduardomaciel/) on 2013-07-11**:\
Hi Shehzi, I tested the new build and is functioning normally. I believe you has dependency problem in your system. Install prerequisites (http://gazebosim.org/wiki/1.6/install#Compile_Instructions).

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-11**:\
Hi EduardoMaciel , davetcoleman. I cloned the git repos again into my catkin_ws/src folder and tried running rosdep install as shown in the tutorial with rosdistro as groovy. It gave the same error as before: cannot find rosdep definition for [gazebo]. I went ahead at did a catkin_make but got the following errors:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5978468. I manually checked for the dependencies using rospack find and all are there. Point to note: Gazebo was installed from debs not source.  

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-11**:\
I installed gazebo from source using the mercurial clone(after removing the previous one using apt-get remove). And now the error is slightly different while installing gazebo_ros_pkgs. The Findgazebo.cmake has worked but FindSDF.cake still remains an issue. Here is the error - https://gist.github.com/shehzaman/5978873

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-11**:\
Hi Shehzi, Gazebo 1.9 has removed the SDF code from within and moved it to an external package. This means if you install Gazebo from source, you'll also need to install SDF from source or install its debian *sdformat*. I've updated the installation page as best as I can for now: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Installing_gazebo_ros_Packages#Install_From_Source

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-11**:\
Hi davetcoleman, I installed gazebo and sdf from source and gazebo works well. After that I tried installing the gazebo\_ros\_pkgs and got these errors - https://gist.github.com/shehzaman/5980202 Its entirely different, but seems to be an issue with sdf headers. I looked for the sdf headers and they are installed in the right place. Don't know why this is happening. Thank you for being active!

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-11**:\
HI davetcoleman, found a hint while reading the log of the build for gazebo\_ros\_pkgs. The make includes /usr/include/gazebo-1.9 and /usr/include/gazebo-1.9/gazebo but only includes /usr/include/sdf-1.4. When I added /usr/include/sdf-1.4/sdf to the CMakeCache.txt in the build directory, catkin\_make worked properly and all the nodes are showing up on rostopic. Hope this helps you debug. 

**Comment by [davetcoleman](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/134/davetcoleman/) on 2013-07-12**:\
update your git checkout of gazebo\_ros\_pkgs

**Comment by [Shehzi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/417/shehzi/) on 2013-07-12**:\
Hi, davetcoleman the file was generated after the failed build. I'm not sure what you want me to checkout in git. I've answered below for the changes I made to make the installation work.
```